# How to avoid a synchronizationlockexception?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I`ve got this error in Monitor.Exit(resource);
This error always appears if i use Monitor.TryEnter(resource) and then exit it after several methods.I wanted to use it with "ref bool" as a lock but it doesn't work.

```
Monitor.TryEnter(fork[second]);
if (Monitor.TryEnter(fork[second])&&fork[second].IsUsing == false)
{
  fork[second].IsUsing = true;
  del.Invoke(String.Format("Ph {0} took  {1} ", philosopherName, second + 1));

  PauseCheck(rd.Next(60, 100));
  Monitor.TryEnter(fork[number]);
  if (Monitor.TryEnter(fork[number])&&fork[number].IsUsing == false)
  {
    entermon1 = true;
    Monitor.Exit(fork[second]);
    fork[number].IsUsing = true;
    Monitor.Exit(fork[number]);
    checkph = true; DonotNeed = true;
  }

  if (entermon1 == false)
  {
    Monitor.Exit(fork[second]);
  }
  entermon1 = false;                            
}
```

Comment: can you post up some code that shows the error?

Comment: Why you don't use locks (what you try to do is like calling `Dispose` manually instead of using `using`)

Comment: @Xaqron: No, it's not - it would be if here were just using `Monitor.Enter`, but `Monitor.TryEnter` *attempts* to acquire a lock, but doesn't block forever if the lock can't be acquired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't lock on value types - only on *objects*, and you definitely don't want to lock on a boxed value unless you're *maintaining* a reference to that box.

My guess is that you're calling `Monitor.Exit` after `Monitor.TryEnter` returned false due to another thread owning the lock - you should only exit the lock if you already own it.

Comment: can i check if the monitor entered                  if(Monitor.TryEnter(object x)){}

Comment: @Tirmit: Yes, that's exactly why `TryEnter` returns a `bool`. (You don't want the `object` part there though - you're calling a method, not declaring it.)

Comment: but can i check if it is entered after trying to enter it?

Comment: @Tirmit: The method returns a value. If you need to use that value more than once, store it in a variable.

Comment: bool x=Monitor.TryEnter(object x); in this case I will be able to try to enter the monitor and get the value to check if i have entered it ,am i right?

Comment: @Tirmit: No, that won't work - you're still adding `object` in a method *call* for no obvious reason, and you're trying to use the name` x` twice... but yes, you call the method and use the returned value.

Comment: sorry it's my fault about the name of vars, so if                     bool z=Monitor.TryEnter(object x); will it be okey? and if i am not right ,can you write the correct one?

Comment: @Tirmit: Why are you *still* including `object` in the method call? Out of interest, how much C# experience to you have? If you're new to the language, could I gently suggest that diving into threading isn't a great idea to start with...